# Hilbert's Hotel - why do we sort the rooms?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Suppose we have one variation of Hilbert's hotel problem:

Suppose we have infinitely many hotels, each with infinitely many rooms, and we want to close all other hotels except one, and we need to accommodate all guests from the closed hotels to the single open one. We are tasked to explain that it is possible to do so, and we need to describe how we would accommodate a guest $(n,m)$, who currently resides in the $n$th room of the $m$th hotel.

One explanation would be if we have a matrix-like structure whose rows would denote the hotels, and whose columns would denote rooms, so that each cell is a $(h,r)$ pair, where $h$ is hotel and $r$ is room. Next, we *sort* all pairs $(h,r)$ by the sum of $h+r$, of course ascending. The list would go as follows: $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (2,2)...$

Next, we simply assign all the natural numbers to each pair, so that $1 \rightarrow (1,1)$, $2 \rightarrow (1,2)$ etc, so that each guest from hotel $h$ and room $r$ will be assigned to room number $n$ which corresponds to the pair.

**My question is:** What is the point of sorting the pairs? It may be a naive question, and admittedly I can't find another way to do it, but it's evident that this matrix is an infinite one so why couldn't we just simply said that it is possible?

Comment: It is because there are different infinities, some larger than the others. The fact that two sets are infinite does not imply that their elements can be put in 1-1 correspondence. The most famous examples: (1) $\mathbb R$ is strictly larger than $\mathbb N$; (2) For any set $X$, the set $\mathcal P(X)$ of _subsets_ of $X$ is strictly larger than $X$ itself  ([Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)).

Comment: (To pre-empt some comments from experts ... I say "larger" to mean this: $X$ larger than $Y$ if there is an _injection_ of $Y$ into $X$, and "strictly larger" to mean this: $X$ is larger than $Y$ but there is no _bijection_ of $Y$ into $X$. There may be other definitions that may be only equivalent to this one if you accept Axiom of Choice.)

Comment: To find an explicit bijection $f\colon \mathbb N \to X$ is precisely what intuitive idea of sorting is. You can also prove that two sets are equipotent without explicit "sorting" using cardinal arithmetic and/or Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem.